# Spring Data Interface Projection

Tags: spring-data, projection

i want to select only on column from my entity.
For this purpose i use interface based projection.

Entity

```
public class FilterMaterial implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private long id;

    Column(name="AC_TYPE")
    private String acType;

    Column(name="LPLAN_ORK")
    private String lplanOrk;

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   
    public String getAcType() {
        return this.acType;
    }
    public void setAcType(String acType) {
        this.acType = acType;
    }   
    public String getLplanOrk() {
        return lplanOrk;
    }
    public void setLplanOrk(String lplanOrk) {
        this.lplanOrk = lplanOrk;
    }
}
```

For the projection i've defined interface like in documentation
I want to select only column LPLAN_ORK

```
public interface FilterMaterialDesc {
    String getLplanOrk()();
}
```

At next i've defined namedQuery:

```
List<FilterMaterialDesc> findDescByAcType(String acType);
```

So, want to select only one column LPLAN_ORK. For this i am using as return-type FilterMaterialDesc type.
It works well, but i select all columns and not only one, which i wish.
What i've forgot to do?

Comment: please share a method where `findDescByAcType` is invoking and an SQL trace that has been populated by it

Comment: findDescByAcType is NamedParameter-proxy-function. There is no implementation by myself

Comment: @RomaKap could you please share what Spring (Boot, Data) version are you using?

Comment: @MarceloBarros hi it is: org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.9.5.RELEASE:compile